# Error while uploading image file using Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, flask-uploads

**Error**
while uploading files to my  selected folder it raises the following error.

As I am new to flask I am unable to catch the error.

**Not Found**

**The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.**

**app.py**

```
import os
#import magic
import urllib.request
#from app import app
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
app = Flask(__name__)

#app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/static'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/')
def upload_form():
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the files part
        if 'files[]' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        files = request.files.getlist('files[]')
        for file in files:
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        flash('File(s) successfully uploaded')
        return redirect('/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

upload.html

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Python Flask Multiple Files Upload Example</title>
<h2>Select file(s) to upload</h2>
<p>
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
      {% if messages %}
        <ul class=flashes>
        {% for message in messages %}
          <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
</p>
<form method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <dl>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="true" autocomplete="off" required>
        </p>
    </dl>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Some error show your path is not found.
Please change your code to @app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
and in upload.html <form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your code

```
    @app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the files part
        if 'files[]' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        files = request.files.getlist('files[]')
        for file in files:
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        flash('File(s) successfully uploaded')
        return redirect('/')
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('upload.html')
```